# A MySQL Stored Routine to create a Crosstab table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table (tab) with 3 columns. Here's a little sample:

```
element_name |  data_timestamp |  data_in
Port1           2013-10-01        4335
Port1           2013-10-02        4335
Port1           2013-10-03        4365
Port1           2013-10-04        4375
Port2           2013-10-01        3335
Port2           2013-10-02        3335
Port2           2013-10-03        3365
Port2           2013-10-04        3375
Port3           2013-10-01        7335
Port3           2013-10-02        7335
Port3           2013-10-03        7365
Port3           2013-10-04        7375
```

I could have any distinct number of "elemment_name"s, so I need a crosstab table that has a dynamic number of columns. In my sample, I would want:

```
Port1 | Port2 | Port3 | Date
4335    3335    7335    2013-10-01
4335    3335    7335    2013-10-02
4365    3365    7365    2013-10-03
4375    3375    7375    2013-10-04
```

I have not found a clean way of doing this, so I wrote a Stored Routine:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `makecrosstab`()
BEGIN

DECLARE hdrs TEXT; 
DECLARE value_name varchar(100);
DECLARE value_date datetime;
DECLARE datapoint INT(11);
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE data_cur CURSOR FOR

SELECT  REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(tab.element_name,'\n',' '),' ','_'),'.','_'),'(',''),')','') as col, 
        tab.data_timestamp, tab.data_in
        FROM tab
        order by tab.element_name, tab.data_timestamp;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET no_more_rows = TRUE;

SET @colm = '';
SET @ddl = '';

drop temporary table if exists grid;

SELECT concat(group_concat(distinct REPLACE(REPLACE(replace(replace(replace(tab.element_name,'\n',' '),' ','_'),'.','_'),'(',''),')','')),',') into hdrs
FROM tab; 

WHILE (LOCATE(',', hdrs) > 0)
    DO
        SET @value = ELT(1, hdrs);
        SET @STR = SUBSTRING(hdrs, 1, LOCATE(',',hdrs)-1);
        SET hdrs = SUBSTRING(hdrs, LOCATE(',', hdrs) + 1);
        SET @ddl = concat(@ddl , @STR , ' INT(11) default 0,');  
    END WHILE;
    SET @ddl = concat('create temporary table grid (',@ddl , ' measurement_date datetime);');

    PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    insert into grid (measurement_date) select distinct data_timestamp from tab;

    OPEN data_cur;
        the_loop: LOOP

            FETCH  data_cur
            INTO   value_name,value_date,datapoint;

            IF no_more_rows THEN
                CLOSE data_cur;
                LEAVE the_loop;
            END IF;

            SET @colm = concat('update grid set ',value_name ,' = ', datapoint, ' where measurement_date = ''',value_date,''';');
            PREPARE stmt FROM @colm;
               EXECUTE stmt;
               DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
        END LOOP the_loop;

select * from grid;
END
```

I can't help but to think there is a better way, but have not been able to find any solutions if you don't know how many columns your resultset will have.

Does anyone know of a simpler solution?

Comment: Use Excel, connect into the database and create a pivot table based on the table in the database. This isn't a programmatic solution but if all you're after is the data for reporting, it seems like it may suit your needs.

Comment: Don't confuse issues of data storage with those of data retrieval and display. Typically, this kind of thing would be handled in the presentation layer/application level code (e.g. php) using a simple loop.

Comment: Good comment, but unfortunately I'm writing a reporting tool where the user will just click a link and the report is generated. So, the manual use of Excel is not an option, as new data is added every day.

Comment: Strawberry, I agree, but in this case I want the ability to use the results to join to other tables for more complicated reports. I guess I'm basically looking for opinions on how I created the crosstab result. Is there a mainstream way of doing this that I'm overlooking? I can use what I did. I just want to make sure I have not overlooked the obvious solution.

Comment: @DavidKinkead Excel is hardly a static tool. It offers automatic data refresh and a fairly robust filtering mechanism. You can generate your report without any link clicking.

Comment: @DavidKinkead Happy to be proved wrong but, I cannot imagine a query whose complexity is simplified (or performance improved) by this process. That said, if I was going to adopt a pure MySQL solution, then yours is the one I'd adopt.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://web.archive.org/web/20100412091116/http://www.futhark.ch/mysql/106.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following stored procedure can give you some ideas to simplify your method:

```sql
/* CODE FOR DEMONSTRATION PURPOSES */
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_cross_tab`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE `done` INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE `en` VARCHAR(5);
    DECLARE `crosstab` TEXT DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE `cur` CURSOR FOR
        SELECT `element_name`
        FROM `tab`
        GROUP BY `element_name`;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` = TRUE;
    OPEN `cur`;
    `read_loop`: LOOP
        FETCH `cur` INTO `en`;
        IF `done` THEN
            LEAVE `read_loop`;
        END IF;
        SET `crosstab` := CONCAT(`crosstab`, 'SUM(IF(`element_name` = \'', `en`, '\', `data_in`, 0)) AS `', `en`, '`,');
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE `cur`;
    SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT ', `crosstab`, ' `data_ts` FROM `tab` GROUP BY `data_ts`');
    PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
    SET @`query` := NULL; 
    EXECUTE `stmt`;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97766e/1)</kbd>

Comment: This is good stuff. I'll play with it. It definitely looks a little less complicated. Thanks a bunch wchiquito!